# UICollectionView with pictures

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview

I am trying to appear pictures into the cells that related to UICollectionViewCell. but for some reasons the pictures do not appear on the cells and also when I run the app is shows some errors

here's the error first.
**libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**

and this is my codes
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLLOi.jpg)

thanks

Comment: Do not show images of code. Show _code_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious issue would be that you have no view with tag 2 set. Since you are forcing the value, instead of checking if you actually get a value there, you might get an exception at that point if the call to viewWithTag returns nil.

Try changing this line:

```
var imageView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
```

To something like this:

```
if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as? UIImageView {
    // Set the image here
}
```

If you don't get the crash after that, then the issue is in that bit of code. If you still get a crash, you might want to try uploading your project somewhere and then posting a link here so that anybody interested can take a look to see what is going on.